# Trying to use AppCompatActivity, getting ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse

I am currently trying to implement the AppCompatActivity in my project and I always get following error when starting the app:

```
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
```

I already read many answers to this topic here but it still doesn't work.

In my libs folder there are "android-support-v4.jar" and "android-support-v7.jar". They are added to the Build Path and under "Order and Export" I checked: "Android 4.0.3" "Android Dependencies" "Maven Dependencies" "Android Private Libraries" and the two jars.

And I cleaned and rebuilded the project of course.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: It is time to switch to Android Studio. The import with gradle resolves many of this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not seeing the resource class for your appcopat library try adding the v7 library as a project instead of adding as a jar file....adding as a jar file works for v4 but for v7 you need to add it along with resources....i recommend using android studio its much more user friendly...hope this helps
follow [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) link on how to do it

Comment: Thanks but we have to use eclipse at work atm ;D I will try it with adding it as a project

Answer (score 0):

im not sure but do you have this within your gradle?

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```